# what is the best maching learning algorithm in my situation

Tags: machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, data-science

Assume that a tourist has no idea about the city to visit , I want to recommend **top 10 cities** based on his features about the city (budgetToTravel , isCoastel , isHitorical , withFamily, etc ...).
 My dataset contains features for every city for exemple :

1. Venice Italy 
   (budgetToTravel='5000' , isCoastel=1 , isHistorical =1 , withFamily=1,...)
2. Berlin Germany (BudgetToTravel='6000' ,isHistorical=1, isCoastel =0 , withFamily=1 ,...).

---

**I want to know the best algorithm of machine learning  to recommend the top 10 cities to visit based on the features of a tourist .**

Comment: A nearest neighborhood should work as first approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated Pierre S. you can start with[KNearestNeigbours](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/neighbors.html#unsupervised-neighbors)

This algorithm will allow you do exactly what you want by doing:

```
n_cities_to_recommend = 10
neigh = NearestNeighbors(2, radius=1.0) # you need to play with radius here o scale your data to [0, 1] with [scaler][2]
neigh.fit(cities)

user_input = [budgetToTravel, isCoastel, isHistorical, withFamily, ...]

neigh.kneighbors([user_input], n_cities_to_recommend, return_distance=False) # this will return you closest entities id's from cities
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use (unsupervised) clustering algorithm like Hierarchical Clustering or K-Means Clustering to have clusters of 10 and then you can match the person (tourist) features with the clusters.